# utf-8 path in master..xp_cmdshell command

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, directory, path, xp-cmdshell

How can I execute `master..xp_cmdshell` in SQL Server with path that includes `utf-8` chars
the code works well in another servers and in cmd but not in sql

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'dir \\my-drive\users\myUser\utf8_folder_name\'
```

Pay attention to the path:
*\\my-drive\users\myUser\**utf8_folder_name**\*
when I call to upper folder - without utf-8 chars but same security, the command works correctly
(*\\my-drive\users\myUser\*  -no utf8 chars)
I also tried to wrap the path with quotation

The error is:

| output |
| --- |
| The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. |
| NULL |

Comment: Why do you want to use `xp_cmdshell` is the first place? Though you are passing a `varchar`, *not* an `nvarchar`, so any characters outside of the code page for your collation will be lost.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` has security implications, avoid if possible. You can just open a `cmd.exe` window and do the same. For a Agent Job, you can use a Powershell step

Answer (score 0):

Add `N` before

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell N'dir \\my-drive\users\myUser\utf8_folder_name\'
```